# react native: there is way to display Ionicon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

i try to display the icons but its give me an error :
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `name` of value `ios-arrow-down-circle` supplied to `Icon`

```
renderHeader = section => {
    let index = this.state.activeSections[0];
    let currentObj = this.state.section[index];
    console.log('state', section);
    return (
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize: 20}}>{section.tableHeadAccordion}</Text>
        <Ionicon
            size={25}
            color={"black"}
            name={
              currentObj == section
                ? "ios-arrow-forward-circle" 
                : "ios-arrow-down-circle"
            }
          />
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Comment: are you sure ios-arrow-down-circle exists? Ionicons has 
ios-arrow-dropdown-circle but no 
ios-arrow-down-circle

Comment: Try using `arrow-forward-circle-outline` and `arrow-down-circle-outline`

Comment: Search if icon exist https://ionicons.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Native Vector icons, might be worth double checking the icon name here: https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

Answer (score 0):

The name don't exist in the repository of the lib:

https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

Besides is a Ionicon as well you need to verify if it exists in the repository and the package is suported.

The packages are:

AntDesign,
Entypo,
EvilIcons,
Feather,
FontAwesome,
FontAwesome,
Fontisto,
Foundation,
Ionicons,
MaterialIcons,
MaterialCommunityIcons,
Octicons,
Zocial,
SimpleLineIcons,

The others don't are suplied by the lib.

Answer (score 0):

Names of the icons are different in packages, especially in react-native-vector-icons.

Try these names "`ios-arrow-dropdown`" and "`ios-arrow-dropright`".